# PHP NuSOAP parameters not included in request

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I am trying to send a SOAP request with a header and lots of parameters. This is not the first time I have used NuSOAP and have never had problems with it before. However what is new to me is I am including a header which may be what is causing the problem. Below is the code for my request:

```
 $client = new nusoap_client($url,'wsdl','','','','');

 $header = 
 "<ETGHeader>
  <VersionRequest>1.0.0</VersionRequest>
  <Originator>
    <Signature>Signature</Signature>
    <LoginData>
      <Name>Name</Name>
      <Password>Password</Password>
    </LoginData>
  </Originator>
 </ETGHeader>";
 $client->setHeaders($header);

 $param = array(
    "Settings" => array(
        "param1" => "1",
        "param2" => "2",
        "param3" => "3"
    )
 );

// Call the WebService
$result = $client->call('GetListVehicleType', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```

Here is the request that is being sent:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ETGHeader>
  <VersionRequest>1.0.0</VersionRequest>
  <Originator>
    <Signature>Signature</Signature>
    <LoginData>
      <Name>Name</Name>
      <Password>Password</Password>
    </LoginData>
  </Originator>
</ETGHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><GetListVehicleType xmlns="http://url"/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

None of my parameters are being included in the request.

Any help much appreciated

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with NuSOAP, recoded it using PHP's inbuilt [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and got it working.